# Relacionar PBI con SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, powerbi

Necesito saber si es posible y, de ser posible,cómo extraer las queries de Power BI desde SQL Management Services.

Necesito saber las dependencias de un workflow y sus efectos.

Para ello necesito sacar una query que extraiga las querys de los Power BI que forman el proyecto.

De modo que tendría una Query que busca palabras en todos los procedimientos almacenados, otra query que busca palabras en todas las queries de los reporting services, y otra para analizar las queries de los Power BI,

Alguien sabe si eso es posible, y de serlo, 
¿como hacer la relación?

Gracias.

Comment: No se si lo que entnedi esta mal o esta mal tu redaccion, quieres desde SQL extraer querys que tienes en Power BI o es lo contrario, quieres ejecutar querys desde Power Bi que estan en sql server?

Comment: Entendiste bien, quiero desde SQL Server sacar las queries que realizan las tablas de Power BI, De modo que se pueda saber en todo momento las tablas afectadas en cada informe.

Comment: Hola @user134775, te damos la bienvenida a StackOverflow en español. Completa el [tour] para aprender más sobre el sitio y su funcionamiento general (y así ganarás tu primera medalla). Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Management podría acceder a power bi desktop si obtienes el lugar donde está corriendo con DAX Studio (que en mi opinión es mejor herramienta para esto). Esto solo te permitirá consultar el actual modelo para obtener datos del mismo o metadata.

Para poder exportar esa información tal vez deberías probar una aplicación externa como Power Bi Helper o entrar al editor de consulta y copiar para cada tabla lo que está en el editor avanzado (que es toda la consulta power query antes del modelo)

Saludos